# jQuery Mobile & JS Frameworks

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, knockout.js

At my work we have an existing ASP.NET web application and are duplicating some of the pages & functionality to better target our mobile users. We are using the jQuery Mobile framework and ASP.NET Web Forms to do this.

Since this is going to target the mobile web I would like it to be fast & lightweight which means turning off the view state, loading lists on demand (when opened), and I'd like to eliminate post backs (annoying & doesn't work well w/ jQuery Mobile). Of course this means doing a lot more work client side.

One of the pages is a bit complex, it allows the user to log items, however it's layout is fully customizable. Prior to logging the user is able to define what fields they wish to track. Some of these fields are system designated but others are created by the user. They can choose from a checkbox, dropdown list, date box, radio button, text box, or list box. Some fields are also tied to other fields meaning the user can select an item in one drop down list which then reloads another drop down list with the associated data. The user also has the ability to add an unlimited amount of additional fields (drop down lists) while on the actual page used to log their item. Once the page is filled out by the user the selected fields values are saved back to the server in a database table.

I figured this would be a great chance to use a JS Framework like Knockout.js, the dependency tracking would come in great for trying to keep things synced up & reload lists as needed based on selections made in other lists. Even though I am a bit concerned about how it would handle the fact that the form layout is dynamic & can be modified once displayed (anyone know if it can handle this?).

So I started looking around for jQuery Mobile & Knockout.js and apparently there are issues, workarounds, limitations, etc. w/ the two working together and I saw the same thing w/ Backbone.js

Does anyone have any suggestions w/ this? Is it worth the hassle to try and use a JS Framework of some sort w/ jQuery Mobile? Can a JS Framework handle the form I am trying to create w/o me having to jump through hoops? Am I better off looking for some sort of dependency tracking plugin and just using that and if so can you suggest any that will wire up to my model object & other controls on the page & work correctly w/ jQuery Mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall, knockout should be a good fit for your requirements.  I'm currently using it an MVC3 applicaiton to do similar things to what you are describing.

As for your complex page, this is all doable.

- Your highly customizable form.  This is one area where knockout really shines.  It allows a separation be how data is displayed and the data itself.  This can be done with different data-bindings types and you can add your own customized bindings.  I actually do this a lot when creating a form and experimenting with what the test control type is.
- Dynamic Layout - With Knockout there is no direct connection between the DOM and the data.  Knockout's data-bind statements allow you to connect new content to it's data at run time.  This currently works well in my current app.
- For your requirement about unlimited adds, take a look at the [Contacts Editor Demo](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html).  It seems to have features to do the unlimited requirements

In general with knockout, once I went to using ajax to handle all my data requirements, things became greatly simplified.

As far as using knockout with jQuery mobile, knockout is now part of the new releases of Asp.Net Mvc4, developer preview.  It is my understanding that knockout is key to MVC's design on building single page web offline where the data is stored locally, then dynamically added to the displayed page.  Cannot find link right know, but I'll keep looking and post edit later.

Hope this helps out.  Also, checkout the links on [knockoutjs.net](http://knockoutjs.net) home page. -

Comment: Thanks for the info, the Contacts Editor Demo looks helpful. I wasn't aware of Knockout.js being wrapped in MVC4, good to know.